# max_vel_theta parameter?

Tags: navigation, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

In the source code "*trajectory_planner_ros.cpp*" of *base_local-planner*,
I didn't see it retrieve the value of the parameter **max_vel_theta**.
(You can confirm it with following command)

```
grep -R 'param("max_vel_theta"' *    // I got a empty response
```

But in my test, the parameter value DID control the in_place rotational velocity when the robot start to move to a goal.
Is there anybody can tell me how the parameter value work??

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223039/max_vel_theta-parameter?/) by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2015-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-12-25**:
Seems that trajectory_planner.cpp fetches it from dynamic reconfigure. According to [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/28327/dynamic-reconfigure-default-parameters/) dynreconf might get its value from the parameter server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's retrieved from dynamic_reconfigure. The dynamic_reconfigure callback will be called once when the node is up.

---

Originally posted by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) with karma: 159 on 2015-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0